# Is there a way to send Memory Warning to iPhone device manually?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, memory-warning

I got one problem these days. I'm using an image-cache library, it works well but eventually i met memory issue and the app just quit itself (I guess it's because it just runs out of memory). After read the source code from the image-cache library, i found it's said that when there's memory warning event, it would release all images cached (the images are huge). Is there anyway for me to send Memory warning event to the device manually and directly ? I'm using xcode instrument tool to evaluate the memory usage.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can manually simulate in the simulator:

```
Hardware -> Simulate Memory Warning
```

You can also simulate it programmatically:

```
- (void)simulateMemoryWarning
{
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
  #ifdef DEBUG
    CFNotificationCenterPostNotification(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(),    (CFStringRef)@"UISimulatedMemoryWarningNotification", NULL, NULL, true);
  #endif
#endif
}

CFNotificationCenterPostNotification(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(), (CFStringRef)@"UISimulatedMemoryWarningNotification", NULL, NULL, true);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784892/simulate-memory-warnings-from-the-code-possible Mentions an undocumented API as well

Answer (score 12):

Memory warning can be produced by calling an private method of UIApplication. It works fine on iOS 6.1 and below

```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication]performSelector:@selector(_performMemoryWarning)];
```

NOTE: Remove that selector call before submitting app to iTunes, otherwise it will be rejected.

Comment: DONOT forget to remove this before submitting the app to Apple, use it only for testing, other wise your app will be rejected.

Comment: This does nothing in Xcode 5 with iOS 7