# Programmatic memory Warning ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, memory-management

I want to test out my app in low memory conditions. Previously my approach to this was running

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:[UIApplication sharedApplication] selector:@selector(_performMemoryWarning) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

but it does not work anymore. And by working I mean the *didReceiveMemoryWarning* is not called. I've also tried:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification object: [UIApplication sharedApplication]]; 
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification object: nil];
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] _performMemoryWarning];
```

But none of the above seem to work.

Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: If it doesn't even work when you use the simulator hardware menu (as you suggest in your comment on the answer) then it's more likely that the problem is in your function. Which class isn't receiving the method? When did it stop working? Have you overridden the method and not called super?

Comment: I have overridden the method and I have called super. As you say the class(es) does not receive the call.

Comment: Seems like a backgroundView caught it

Answer (score 1):

Look at this post 
[Is there a way to send Memory Warning to iPhone device manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410901/is-there-a-way-to-send-memory-warning-to-iphone-device-manually)

Send programmatically: `CFNotificationCenterPostNotification(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(), (CFStringRef)@"UISimulatedMemoryWarningNotification", NULL, NULL, true);`

In simulator:

Hardware -> Simulate Memory Warning

Comment: thanks for your answer. Just tried it out and it does not trigger the didReceiveMemoryWarning function

Comment: you also may try to allocate a lot of memory to some dummy variable

Comment: i dont want to take that approach

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to test memory warning code is to build to the simulator and click on

> Hardware ==> Simulate Memory Warning