# Low Memory Warning always causing crash on iPad (1st generation)

Tags: ios, ipad, memory

One of my beta testers with an 1st generation iPad (iOS 5.0.1) is complaining of constant crashing.  From the way it is described to us we are sure that the crash happens as the device receives a low memory warning.

To prove this we gave the tester a version of the build that did not push the memory enough for a low memory warning and it works fine.  But this is not a fix.

We have a good 20 1st generation iPads as beta testers and none of them are having this same issue.

Is it possible that something could be set on the device that might cause it to crash on low memory warning?

Could iOS 5.0.1 have been installed incorrectly?

Has anyone got any idea why this device in particular is crashing on low memory warnings and no other?

Any help would be much appreciated,
- Rich

Comment: Have you tried getting the crash log from the device and get any information from it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be sure, you should try to get the crash log from the device. The tester has to sync the device with iTunes, and then navigate to the folder where iTunes copied any crash reports. This depends on what platform you are using.

```
Mac OS X: ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/<DEVICE_NAME>
Windows XP: C:\Documents and Settings\<USERNAME>\Application Data\Apple Computer\Logs\CrashReporter\MobileDevice\<DEVICE_NAME>
Windows Vista or 7: C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\Logs\CrashReporter\MobileDevice\<DEVICE_NAME>
```

`<USERNAME>` is the user's login name for the computer. `<DEVICE_NAME>` is the name of the iPod touch or iPhone, for example, "My iPhone".

There are ways to collect the crash reports automatically, I posted an overview on the possibilities as part of another answer here: [Including custom data into iOS crash dumps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488894/including-custom-data-into-ios-crash-dumps/8511100#8511100)

In addition you can automate memory warnings when testing in the iOS simulator. Subclass `UIViewController` and automatically trigger memory warnings whenever the view controller appears.

Here is some example code on how to do that:

```
#import "BaseViewController.h"

@interface BaseViewController (Private)
- (void)simulateMemoryWarning;
@end

@implementation BaseViewController

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];

#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#if defined (CONFIGURATION_Debug)
  // If we are running in the simulator and it's the DEBUG target
  // then simulate a memory warning. Note that the DEBUG flag isn't
  // defined by default. To define it add this Preprocessor Macro for
  // the Debug target: DEBUG=1
  [self simulateMemoryWarning];
#endif
#endif
}

- (void)simulateMemoryWarning {
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#if defined (CONFIGURATION_Debug)
  SEL memoryWarningSel = @selector(_performMemoryWarning);
  if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:memoryWarningSel]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] performSelector:memoryWarningSel];
  } else {
    NSLog(@"%@",@"Whoops UIApplication no loger responds to -_performMemoryWarning");
  }
(CFStringRef)@"UISimulatedMemoryWarningNotification", NULL, NULL, true);
#endif
#endif
}

@end
```

Now use this when subclassing your own view controller instead of subclassing from UIViewController. This code was originally posted here https://gist.github.com/956403 and adjusted to work with Xcode 4.2.1 by adding the solution from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2785175/474794

Comment: Not sure why this question was closed since some of our users are on this hardware and software and seeing the same issue.  We did see that after some time, low memory warnings would pop up more frequently than usual, to the point of the iPad becoming unusable.  The solution posted here, simply to RESET ALL SETTINGS, cleared up the issue quickly.   http://www.jackenhack.com/ipad-first-gen-crashing/

Answer (score 1):

I am an iPad 1 user running 5.0.1 and I have this problem all the time with all kinds of apps(Safari, Dropbox, Pages, Angry Birds, Spice Bandits, etc). If you want crash logs I would be happy to provide as many as you like.

The only way I can get games to run for a decent amount of time is to turn off almost all extra "service" (email, notifications, location), and then do a fresh restart of the device. Then force all processes to close. I have restored the device and put everything back on just before 5.1 came out.

If you have a specific app you would like me to test I would be happy to.

I have an iPad 3G 16GB

Andre