# Uninformative Crash Reports

Tags: ios, crash, crash-reports, symbolicatecrash

One of our apps is consistently reporting crashes (using PLCrashReporter) that are very uninformative, it always crashes on Thread 0 and only lists main.m at the bottom of the stack as the offending line in our code.

Also in most cases in one thread (in this case Thread 5) `[ASIHTTPRequest runRequests]` is listed. I am having a very hard time determining what action to take to resolve this issue. Is there any direction that anyone can provide on this? Also interesting is that this App generates MANY different crash groups (similar crashes) whereas our other apps have a pretty consistent ratio of crashes:crash groups, this app it is like 2-3 crashes per crash group with ALOT of groups where it is usually upwards of 20-100s of crashes per crash group with just a few groups.

Another thing, I cannot for the life of me get Xcode/symbolicatecrash to symbolicate the system framework lines. I think at least having these lines symbolicated could help point me in a direction, but for now I am at a loss.

Any suggestions?

```
Incident Identifier: [TODO]
CrashReporter Key:   [TODO]
Process:         MyApp [4815]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/6497DD3A-79B5-4E6B-87C9-65D77BD45E6B/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:      com.company.myapp
Version:         1.7.6
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-05-16 18:44:57 +0000
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0xd0000008
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3665ff78 0x3665c000 + 16248
1   Foundation                          0x345dc4ff 0x3454d000 + 587007
2   CoreFoundation                      0x33d30547 0x33cab000 + 546119
3   CoreFoundation                      0x33cbc097 0x33cab000 + 69783
4   Foundation                          0x345503eb 0x3454d000 + 13291
5   Foundation                          0x34551c1b 0x3454d000 + 19483
6   UIKit                               0x368d80ed 0x36723000 + 1790189
7   UIKit                               0x368d81e7 0x36723000 + 1790439
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x325912e1 0x3258c000 + 21217
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3258eb81 0x3258c000 + 11137
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x3258eec1 0x3258c000 + 11969
11  CoreFoundation                      0x33d372ad 0x33cab000 + 574125
12  CoreFoundation                      0x33cba4a5 0x33cab000 + 62629
13  CoreFoundation                      0x33cba36d 0x33cab000 + 62317
14  GraphicsServices                    0x37c9c439 0x37c98000 + 17465
15  UIKit                               0x36754cd5 0x36723000 + 203989
16  MyApp                              0x00002077 main (main.m:14)

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x307353a8 0x30734000 + 5032
1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3258fc29 0x3258c000 + 15401

Thread 2:
0   WebCore                             0x30dea7f0 0x30c7f000 + 1488880
1   JavaScriptCore                      0x365cef91 0x36536000 + 626577
2   JavaScriptCore                      0x365cef19 0x36536000 + 626457
3   JavaScriptCore                      0x365ca12f 0x36536000 + 606511
4   JavaScriptCore                      0x365ca0f1 0x36536000 + 606449
5   JavaScriptCore                      0x3661eedb 0x36536000 + 954075
6   WebCore                             0x3100f99b 0x30c7f000 + 3738011
7   WebKit                              0x34d18c45 0x34c9c000 + 511045
8   WebCore                             0x30cd50b5 0x30c7f000 + 352437
9   CoreFoundation                      0x33d38ad3 0x33cab000 + 580307
10  CoreFoundation                      0x33d3829f 0x33cab000 + 578207
11  CoreFoundation                      0x33d37045 0x33cab000 + 573509
12  CoreFoundation                      0x33cba4a5 0x33cab000 + 62629
13  CoreFoundation                      0x33cba36d 0x33cab000 + 62317
14  WebCore                             0x30d28ca3 0x30c7f000 + 695459
15  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3536b735 0x3535d000 + 59189

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x30735004 0x30734000 + 4100
1   CoreFoundation                      0x33d383f3 0x33cab000 + 578547
2   CoreFoundation                      0x33d3712b 0x33cab000 + 573739
3   CoreFoundation                      0x33cba4a5 0x33cab000 + 62629
4   CoreFoundation                      0x33cba36d 0x33cab000 + 62317
5   Foundation                          0x3455dbb9 0x3454d000 + 68537
6   Foundation                          0x3455da81 0x3454d000 + 68225
7   Foundation                          0x345f1591 0x3454d000 + 673169
8   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3536b735 0x3535d000 + 59189

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x30745570 0x30734000 + 71024
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3536b735 0x3535d000 + 59189

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x30735004 0x30734000 + 4100
1   CoreFoundation                      0x33d383f3 0x33cab000 + 578547
2   CoreFoundation                      0x33d3712b 0x33cab000 + 573739
3   CoreFoundation                      0x33cba4a5 0x33cab000 + 62629
4   CoreFoundation                      0x33d3744b 0x33cab000 + 574539
5   MyApp                              0x0003bf7b +[ASIHTTPRequest runRequests] (ASIHTTPRequest.m:4779)
6   Foundation                          0x3455da81 0x3454d000 + 68225
7   Foundation                          0x345f1591 0x3454d000 + 673169
8   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3536b735 0x3535d000 + 59189

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x30735004 0x30734000 + 4100
1   CoreFoundation                      0x33d383f3 0x33cab000 + 578547
2   CoreFoundation                      0x33d3712b 0x33cab000 + 573739
3   CoreFoundation                      0x33cba4a5 0x33cab000 + 62629
4   CoreFoundation                      0x33cba36d 0x33cab000 + 62317
5   WebCore                             0x30d520d9 0x30c7f000 + 864473
6   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3536b735 0x3535d000 + 59189

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x30745068 0x30734000 + 69736
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3536b7c9 0x3535d000 + 59337
2   JavaScriptCore                      0x365fb915 0x36536000 + 809237
3   WebCore                             0x30e89be3 0x30c7f000 + 2141155
4   WebCore                             0x30e89b99 0x30c7f000 + 2141081
5   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3536b735 0x3535d000 + 59189

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x30745cd4 0x30734000 + 72916

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x30745cd4 0x30734000 + 72916

Thread 10:
0   ???                                 0x00000000 0x0 + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM (Native) Thread State:
    r0: 0x0eecd480     r1:  0x36b1e9fb     r2:  0x00000000     r3:  0x00000000 
    r4: 0xd0000000     r5:  0x00000000     r6:  0x00000000     r7:  0x2fe94e0c 
    r8: 0x00000000     r9:  0x0dac7a7e    r10:  0x000f4454    r11:  0x00001a60 
   r12: 0x3f587048     sp:  0x2fe94df4     lr:  0x000f9c15     pc:  0x3665ff78 
  cpsr: 0x200f0030 
Binary Images:
0x97000 - 0x19d000  MyApp armv7  /var/mobile/Applications/6497DD3A-79B5-4E6B-87C9-65D77BD45E6B/MyApp.app/MyApp
0x3341e000 - 0x3346d000  CoreLocation armv7 <44550ebedf23334d85441d9743b74e03> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x373ba000 - 0x3743e000  MapKit armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
0x33dc9000 - 0x33fae000  AudioToolbox armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x33119000 - 0x3320b000  QuartzCore armv7 <35d64a9da5523ae08c9e41511fd3061b> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x3754a000 - 0x375f8000  libxml2.2.dylib armv7 <58d47f064e0232119f4b838ad659f9c1> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x30bd0000 - 0x30bdd000  libz.1.dylib armv7 <36ce86a3dc8c344596c8c325615f374b> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x34db3000 - 0x34df8000  MobileCoreServices armv7 <757226927a873d5492be721908077b48> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x304fe000 - 0x30534000  SystemConfiguration armv7 <4464a4e3bb3f32f7abaa35ebf31fda49> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x376e2000 - 0x377ba000  CFNetwork armv7 <765a472c824830eea91b8f02d12867e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x343e4000 - 0x3441c000  Security armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x36723000 - 0x36bc6000  UIKit armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x3454d000 - 0x346cc000  Foundation armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x336ca000 - 0x33810000  CoreGraphics armv7 <903545b89a7f311d95100ac7d1d44709> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x35105000 - 0x352ac000  CoreData armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x34726000 - 0x34746000  libSystem.B.dylib armv7 <0c55744b6f7335eebba4ca2c3d10b43c> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x33cab000 - 0x33dc3000  CoreFoundation armv7 <6d450fe923d7387f8b01845e0edd713d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x3665c000 - 0x36723000  libobjc.A.dylib armv7 <90014d1bc583366d85622e43097df416> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x30ab2000 - 0x30ac2000  SpringBoardServices armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x326c8000 - 0x326cb000  MobileInstallation armv7 <215d93dbb0f63cbf828f9126eb7b5349> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x36196000 - 0x361a0000  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7 <4a15e845dc6f3a4a980de66c1cc44c42> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x34d6d000 - 0x34db3000  GeoServices armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x338a3000 - 0x338e0000  AppSupport armv7 <311eac85b2a433a884dacba77217b49e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x37c98000 - 0x37ca3000  GraphicsServices armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x3499f000 - 0x349de000  IOKit armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x3188f000 - 0x318d9000  AddressBook armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x34169000 - 0x341e9000  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x35cb5000 - 0x35cc0000  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7 <40e4045fb79e382b8833707746cf28b1> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x341e9000 - 0x341ed000  CoreTime armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x33851000 - 0x338a3000  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x3015c000 - 0x302a6000  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x34e12000 - 0x34e13000  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x34a7c000 - 0x34a84000  libc++abi.dylib armv7  /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x3434d000 - 0x34352000  libcache.dylib armv7  /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x30bf0000 - 0x30c34000  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7 <95b49daf4cf038b6bea8010bba3a1e26> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x364ab000 - 0x364af000  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x3384b000 - 0x33851000  libcopyfile.dylib armv7 <52e874396c393ed29099789ce702cfe2> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x3258c000 - 0x325a3000  libdispatch.dylib armv7 <9ecfaef4110a3bf9a92d12f0fe8d1d78> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x36d46000 - 0x36d48000  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7 <9aede8d6579d3430ac39ae5f95cce498> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x356bd000 - 0x356bf000  libdyld.dylib armv7 <977b0ad6f2f433108b4a0324a57cd2ab> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x348a6000 - 0x348a7000  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x30837000 - 0x3083e000  liblaunch.dylib armv7  /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x32142000 - 0x32146000  libmacho.dylib armv7  /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x36bc6000 - 0x36bcd000  libnotify.dylib armv7 <9406297de3e43742887890662a87ab53> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x31d23000 - 0x31d25000  libremovefile.dylib armv7 <402f8956975d3b6fb86ab9b31a43242c> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x361f9000 - 0x361fb000  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7 <9fdc27af7350323bbc7d98e14e027907> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x3535d000 - 0x353ea000  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x30afe000 - 0x30b04000  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7 <27bb5462450732e380f5a2c170546e93> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x31cda000 - 0x31cf8000  libsystem_info.dylib armv7 <50863bcbf478323e96a8e5b1a83ea6f9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x30734000 - 0x3074b000  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7 <311f379a9fde305d80c1b22b7dd2e52a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x327a8000 - 0x327ac000  libsystem_network.dylib armv7 <356cb66612e836968ef24e6e5c3364cc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x30732000 - 0x30734000  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7 <6a8f2f33c7543808a0f4599101c3b61a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x3441c000 - 0x3441d000  libunwind.dylib armv7  /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x30ac2000 - 0x30ad4000  libxpc.dylib armv7  /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x352d8000 - 0x352df000  MobileIcons armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x354b6000 - 0x354c3000  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x36225000 - 0x36226000  liblangid.dylib armv7 <644ff4bcfbf337b5b5859e3f0fc0a9a8> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x34f65000 - 0x34f75000  GenerationalStorage armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x34a84000 - 0x34c42000  ImageIO armv7 <02e3578171fa3b6a969b244275fd2bab> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x3499a000 - 0x3499f000  IOSurface armv7 <443ac3aab9283da480dd9dcda3c5c88e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x35c54000 - 0x35ca1000  CoreTelephony armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x31cd3000 - 0x31cda000  liblockdown.dylib armv7 <9e45ce468a6f31e5b8263f2c224aa800> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x361a0000 - 0x361f9000  CoreAudio armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x35ca5000 - 0x35cb3000  libbsm.0.dylib armv7 <750a0de73a733019a77144b805d4d2f8> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x36e47000 - 0x36e48000  Accelerate armv7 <55b24cf91a8b3532bde6733c96f14c08> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x36173000 - 0x3617a000  MobileKeyBag armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x348a7000 - 0x34980000  vImage armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x375f9000 - 0x375fa000  vecLib armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x33390000 - 0x333db000  libvDSP.dylib armv7 <441b42aca07b3da39feab25f8349918f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x31e80000 - 0x32142000  libLAPACK.dylib armv7 <0e94e9a7e7a334649afaccae0f1215a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x32fd8000 - 0x33083000  libBLAS.dylib armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x352ac000 - 0x352b7000  libvMisc.dylib armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x36d4e000 - 0x36d72000  Bom armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x32583000 - 0x3258c000  ProtocolBuffer armv7 <0e846afacf823d2b8c029cc3010a8253> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x3338b000 - 0x33390000  AggregateDictionary armv7 <3a3a33f3a05538988c6e2bb363dc46a8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x3256f000 - 0x32581000  DataAccessExpress armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x30bcc000 - 0x30bd0000  NetworkStatistics armv7 <7848d8ebad99367cb4f7f4e3fe88e5d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
0x32f8a000 - 0x32f96000  AccountSettings armv7 <373e59421d983c93931cfbad87b1ae35> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x30c34000 - 0x30c7f000  ManagedConfiguration armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x340a1000 - 0x340b8000  libmis.dylib armv7 <258bc92be5823b239b4412dd42cb4807> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x346d7000 - 0x346ec000  PersistentConnection armv7 <54091a638f8731cd85ccf00fa06972c3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x35cb3000 - 0x35cb5000  DataMigration armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x32533000 - 0x3253c000  MobileWiFi armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x31d25000 - 0x31d29000  CaptiveNetwork armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x37c81000 - 0x37c98000  EAP8021X armv7 <952fcfdec0633aff923768fca1a26fcb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x35f43000 - 0x35fea000  AddressBookUI armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x35fea000 - 0x36041000  GMM armv7 <6b2f7e1aa6be3d69b4c4cf54ed960602> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x36041000 - 0x36046000  FTClientServices armv7 <21de970d7ebb3e7fb502a0a5451b0806> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x3075f000 - 0x30764000  libAccessibility.dylib armv7 <9a17d07b5a3b38cfafdf16f78c99b572> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x36536000 - 0x3665c000  JavaScriptCore armv7 <2ffc6c87b94434288366bd53765ee267> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x36ee2000 - 0x36f40000  StoreServices armv7 <6ce256d3cf433e4aa1af8d696bf1f75d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x324cf000 - 0x32533000  IMCore armv7 <046b6b615a743057b59d4aaba8a91d61> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x34c54000 - 0x34c59000  Marco armv7 <8dea3e558fe534ff868fc92e215ce53b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x36131000 - 0x3616f000  FTServices armv7 <3f23418319a03a589dd5cac7df20e238> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x36cbb000 - 0x36cf8000  IMFoundation armv7 <253125b9103c3d13b66923ac6893c25b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/Frameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x36226000 - 0x36253000  libtidy.A.dylib armv7 <3aacc5b650e037c086a8ff6657d154bf> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x3609c000 - 0x3610d000  CoreImage armv7 <86ac6f5a267637b6b7f8a831dfc7c64b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x350b1000 - 0x350c8000  DictionaryServices armv7 <6ed2e967136f37d4a4b9b318d6c43b83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x37165000 - 0x371b7000  CoreText armv7 <5bfac4ee88d03d5b87a1f105abb7756c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x34c9c000 - 0x34d6d000  WebKit armv7 <3c5dd2ec46fe3e189c25bba78ad88fa1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x30c7f000 - 0x3143f000  WebCore armv7 <2690c38c9c5f3c09975d619dd1dfbed7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x36f4c000 - 0x36fc6000  ProofReader armv7 <6db611d8df6530d480f97a40bc519f70> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x34f2f000 - 0x34f54000  PrintKit armv7 <08509c7bc915358b953de6f5cbef5c56> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x314a0000 - 0x314c6000  OpenCL armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x3042d000 - 0x3043d000  OpenGLES armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x30569000 - 0x305a2000  VideoToolbox armv7 <9f25f38d1cd13a1daff99cfde8884410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x327ee000 - 0x32d33000  FaceCoreLight armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x34352000 - 0x3435f000  CoreVideo armv7 <364fa32d513f3c11b50970120545f1a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x33846000 - 0x3384b000  libGFXShared.dylib armv7 <998fccc16cf735dbb62324202995e193> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x30bb7000 - 0x30bba000  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x373b5000 - 0x373ba000  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7 <42dbc26828e934acabb4f3b0a35d8250> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x372bd000 - 0x372fe000  libGLImage.dylib armv7 <40448706190031f6b0d9636cc11ee81d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x36195000 - 0x36196000  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x318f1000 - 0x318f3000  CoreSurface armv7 <97f871f09f503c98a6371c2b657430d8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x37274000 - 0x372bd000  CoreMedia armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x314c6000 - 0x314ce000  AssetsLibraryServices armv7 <38132ecfd74b325fb1a4142bab663c19> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x31919000 - 0x3193a000  libxslt.1.dylib armv7 <39348471007e39dab80af68b08390456> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x37008000 - 0x37052000  libc++.1.dylib armv7 <5b690e5dd5a43a7fb166ade9fe58a7a4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x31d90000 - 0x31e7f000  libiconv.2.dylib armv7 <2cfefe2ad1d335dd9549562910e7a2e2> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x32ed0000 - 0x32ee6000  libresolv.9.dylib armv7 <66f7557fa4b43979b186e00271839fdb> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x34506000 - 0x34542000  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7 <55941c96cf1f3b048e72a148c4496c16> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x300ff000 - 0x30119000  libRIP.A.dylib armv7 <1828cddc5dd93c61afbefb59587d7f8a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x34a17000 - 0x34a32000  CoreServicesInternal armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesInternal.framework/CoreServicesInternal
0x37052000 - 0x37132000  RawCamera armv7 <293f818ba6533dceae8b900b6ed3c887> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
0x3215f000 - 0x324cf000  TextInput armv7 <8d7f24642c7634cc8e3a6e65f1dcd98e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x341ed000 - 0x3434d000  libmecabra.dylib armv7 <06a0a1ee488030169bdfab11fc8d2c5c> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
0x37b76000 - 0x37c3d000  GLEngine armv7 <6617f2b4ee283469a5595129889ff049> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine
0x35de8000 - 0x35eb8000  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7 <49607ffe4ee9389494285a213e392924> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x3743e000 - 0x37545000  IMGSGX543GLDriver armv7 <7454a840600038949d67edad05097242> /System/Library/Extensions/IMGSGX543GLDriver.bundle/IMGSGX543GLDriver
0x31d04000 - 0x31d0a000  libGPUSupportMercury.dylib armv7 <3c1cc3175c403ace8fcbd3826bd43807> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUSupport.framework/libGPUSupportMercury.dylib
0x309fc000 - 0x309ff000  libCoreFSCache.dylib armv7 <808518e0fbf539af8489f028ca5198c7> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x34a54000 - 0x34a67000  DataDetectorsUI armv7 <50ea319aaeb7307e92719980dd4b2953> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsUI.framework/DataDetectorsUI
0x327da000 - 0x327ee000  DataDetectorsCore armv7 <3f4596cbe1b13fdcb427d87de21df3f6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore
0x364b8000 - 0x364f8000  QuickLook armv7 <802b1092542a3017a0380632502610d4> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x3148a000 - 0x3148e000  libgermantok.dylib armv7 <94278987ba623a35ae545db5636b4370> /usr/lib/libgermantok.dylib
0x3262b000 - 0x3263f000  AssistantServices armv7 <4a0843742f363a8885b8db13b44ae256> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssistantServices.framework/AssistantServices
0x37135000 - 0x3714c000  VoiceServices armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VoiceServices.framework/VoiceServices
0x32ee6000 - 0x32f40000  IMAVCore armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMAVCore.framework/IMAVCore
0x31d1d000 - 0x31d23000  CrashReporterSupport armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x5231000 - 0x5242000  Riven armv7 <46e4d9c7b88d3afca369efb40e3ff4d5> /System/Library/TextInput/Riven.bundle/Riven
```

Comment: Does this help you ? http://i45.tinypic.com/34hyy3c.png ...

You could also try settings some user breakpoints like this to help you find the problem : http://i45.tinypic.com/20p57wi.png

Comment: These are coming through a crash reporter, not while debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding system symbols not getting symbolicated: Those are probably not available on your system via spotlight. Did you upgrade a device to 5.1.1 and did Xcode extract the symbols? Check `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport`. It should contain a directory named `5.1.1 (9B206)`.

I did run symbolication of your report above on our (HockeyApp - I am one of the developers) symbolication server and got the following output. This is because the crash report is somehow missing the UUID of those system libraries. Which version of PLCrashReporter are you using? You may want to check out [QuincyKit](http://github.com/therealkerni/quincykit) which contains a newer version of PLCrashReporter than the one on its project website. Hope this helps a bit.

**Edit**: Updated the crashreport by using the UUIDs from another crash in our database and symbolicated the report again. So it looks like the problem is related to a notification that is registered on an object which has been released when your app got a memory warning. You can try to simulate that with the iOS Simulator, or even add code to automatically check for such bugs when testing your app with the simulator, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9311289/474794

```
Incident Identifier: [TODO]
CrashReporter Key:   [TODO]
Process:         MyApp [4815]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/6497DD3A-79B5-4E6B-87C9-65D77BD45E6B/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:      com.company.myapp
Version:         1.7.6
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-05-16 18:44:57 +0000
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0xd0000008
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x361dbf78 objc_msgSend + 16
1   Foundation                          0x34ea14ff __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_0 + 19
2   CoreFoundation                      0x34d86547 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke_0 + 71
3   CoreFoundation                      0x34d12097 _CFXNotificationPost + 1407
4   Foundation                          0x34e153eb -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 67
5   Foundation                          0x34e16c1b -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:] + 31
6   UIKit                               0x32f790ed -[UIApplication _performMemoryWarning] + 81
7   UIKit                               0x32f791e7 -[UIApplication _receivedMemoryNotification] + 175
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x30de42e1 _dispatch_source_invoke + 517
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x30de1b81 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 53
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x30de1ec1 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 157
11  CoreFoundation                      0x34d8d2ad __CFRunLoopRun + 1269
12  CoreFoundation                      0x34d104a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301
13  CoreFoundation                      0x34d1036d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
14  GraphicsServices                    0x36f85439 GSEventRunModal + 137
15  UIKit                               0x32df5cd5 UIApplicationMain + 1081
16  MyApp                              0x00002077 main (main.m:14)

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x35c393a8 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x30de2c29 _dispatch_mgr_wakeup + 1

Thread 2:
0   WebCore                             0x312aa7f0 WebCore::StringSourceProvider::~StringSourceProvider() + 0
1   JavaScriptCore                      0x33a6cf91 JSC::MarkedBlock::sweep() + 101
2   JavaScriptCore                      0x33a6cf19 JSC::MarkedSpace::sweep() + 41
3   JavaScriptCore                      0x33a6812f JSC::Heap::reset(JSC::Heap::SweepToggle) + 55
4   JavaScriptCore                      0x33a680f1 JSC::Heap::collectAllGarbage() + 17
5   JavaScriptCore                      0x33abcedb JSC::JSGlobalData::releaseExecutableMemory() + 395
6   WebCore                             0x314cf99b WebCore::GCController::releaseExecutableMemory() + 35
7   WebKit                              0x350e8c45 +[WebView(WebPrivate) _handleMemoryWarning] + 189
8   WebCore                             0x311950b5 HandleRunSource + 365
9   CoreFoundation                      0x34d8ead3 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
10  CoreFoundation                      0x34d8e29f __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 215
11  CoreFoundation                      0x34d8d045 __CFRunLoopRun + 653
12  CoreFoundation                      0x34d104a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301
13  CoreFoundation                      0x34d1036d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
14  WebCore                             0x311e8ca3 RunWebThread(void*) + 403
15  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x32756735 _pthread_start + 321

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x35c39004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x34d8e3f3 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 127
2   CoreFoundation                      0x34d8d12b __CFRunLoopRun + 883
3   CoreFoundation                      0x34d104a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301
4   CoreFoundation                      0x34d1036d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
5   Foundation                          0x34e22bb9 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 309
6   Foundation                          0x34e22a81 -[NSThread main] + 73
7   Foundation                          0x34eb6591 __NSThread__main__ + 1049
8   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x32756735 _pthread_start + 321

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x35c49570 __select + 20
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x32756735 _pthread_start + 321

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x35c39004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x34d8e3f3 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 127
2   CoreFoundation                      0x34d8d12b __CFRunLoopRun + 883
3   CoreFoundation                      0x34d104a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301
4   CoreFoundation                      0x34d8d44b CFRunLoopRun + 99
5   MyApp                              0x0003bf7b +[ASIHTTPRequest runRequests] (ASIHTTPRequest.m:4779)
6   Foundation                          0x34e22a81 -[NSThread main] + 73
7   Foundation                          0x34eb6591 __NSThread__main__ + 1049
8   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x32756735 _pthread_start + 321

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x35c39004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x34d8e3f3 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 127
2   CoreFoundation                      0x34d8d12b __CFRunLoopRun + 883
3   CoreFoundation                      0x34d104a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301
4   CoreFoundation                      0x34d1036d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
5   WebCore                             0x312120d9 WebCore::runLoaderThread(void*) + 129
6   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x32756735 _pthread_start + 321

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x35c49068 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x327567c9 pthread_cond_wait + 41
2   JavaScriptCore                      0x33a99915 WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 61
3   WebCore                             0x31349be3 WTF::PassOwnPtr<WebCore::LocalStorageTask> WTF::MessageQueue<WebCore::LocalStorageTask>::waitForMessageFilteredWithTimeout<bool ()(WebCore::LocalStorageTask*)>(WTF::MessageQueueWaitResult&, bool (&)(WebCore::LocalStorageTask*), double) + 59
4   WebCore                             0x31349b99 WebCore::LocalStorageThread::threadEntryPointCallback(void*) + 113
5   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x32756735 _pthread_start + 321

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x35c49cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x35c49cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8

Thread 10:
0   ???                                 0x00000000 0x0 + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM (Native) Thread State:
    r0: 0x0eecd480     r1:  0x36b1e9fb     r2:  0x00000000     r3:  0x00000000 
    r4: 0xd0000000     r5:  0x00000000     r6:  0x00000000     r7:  0x2fe94e0c 
    r8: 0x00000000     r9:  0x0dac7a7e    r10:  0x000f4454    r11:  0x00001a60 
   r12: 0x3f587048     sp:  0x2fe94df4     lr:  0x000f9c15     pc:  0x3665ff78 
  cpsr: 0x200f0030 
Binary Images:
0x97000 - 0x19d000  MyApp armv7  /var/mobile/Applications/6497DD3A-79B5-4E6B-87C9-65D77BD45E6B/MyApp.app/MyApp
0x3341e000 - 0x3346d000  CoreLocation armv7 <44550ebedf23334d85441d9743b74e03> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x373ba000 - 0x3743e000  MapKit armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
0x33dc9000 - 0x33fae000  AudioToolbox armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x33119000 - 0x3320b000  QuartzCore armv7 <35d64a9da5523ae08c9e41511fd3061b> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x3754a000 - 0x375f8000  libxml2.2.dylib armv7 <58d47f064e0232119f4b838ad659f9c1> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x30bd0000 - 0x30bdd000  libz.1.dylib armv7 <36ce86a3dc8c344596c8c325615f374b> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x34db3000 - 0x34df8000  MobileCoreServices armv7 <757226927a873d5492be721908077b48> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x304fe000 - 0x30534000  SystemConfiguration armv7 <4464a4e3bb3f32f7abaa35ebf31fda49> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x376e2000 - 0x377ba000  CFNetwork armv7 <765a472c824830eea91b8f02d12867e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x343e4000 - 0x3441c000  Security armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x36723000 - 0x36bc6000  UIKit armv7 <cd513a2f22f53d698c3e10f6fe48a63e> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x3454d000 - 0x346cc000  Foundation armv7 <c40ddb073142315bb4ebb214343d0b7f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x336ca000 - 0x33810000  CoreGraphics armv7 <903545b89a7f311d95100ac7d1d44709> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x35105000 - 0x352ac000  CoreData armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x34726000 - 0x34746000  libSystem.B.dylib armv7 <0c55744b6f7335eebba4ca2c3d10b43c> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x33cab000 - 0x33dc3000  CoreFoundation armv7 <6d450fe923d7387f8b01845e0edd713d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x3665c000 - 0x36723000  libobjc.A.dylib armv7 <90014d1bc583366d85622e43097df416> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x30ab2000 - 0x30ac2000  SpringBoardServices armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x326c8000 - 0x326cb000  MobileInstallation armv7 <215d93dbb0f63cbf828f9126eb7b5349> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x36196000 - 0x361a0000  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7 <4a15e845dc6f3a4a980de66c1cc44c42> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x34d6d000 - 0x34db3000  GeoServices armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x338a3000 - 0x338e0000  AppSupport armv7 <311eac85b2a433a884dacba77217b49e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x37c98000 - 0x37ca3000  GraphicsServices armv7 <cb64e146a8ee3fda9e80ffae1ccc9c5a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x3499f000 - 0x349de000  IOKit armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x3188f000 - 0x318d9000  AddressBook armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x34169000 - 0x341e9000  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x35cb5000 - 0x35cc0000  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7 <40e4045fb79e382b8833707746cf28b1> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x341e9000 - 0x341ed000  CoreTime armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x33851000 - 0x338a3000  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x3015c000 - 0x302a6000  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x34e12000 - 0x34e13000  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x34a7c000 - 0x34a84000  libc++abi.dylib armv7  /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x3434d000 - 0x34352000  libcache.dylib armv7  /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x30bf0000 - 0x30c34000  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7 <95b49daf4cf038b6bea8010bba3a1e26> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x364ab000 - 0x364af000  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x3384b000 - 0x33851000  libcopyfile.dylib armv7 <52e874396c393ed29099789ce702cfe2> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x3258c000 - 0x325a3000  libdispatch.dylib armv7 <9ecfaef4110a3bf9a92d12f0fe8d1d78> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x36d46000 - 0x36d48000  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7 <9aede8d6579d3430ac39ae5f95cce498> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x356bd000 - 0x356bf000  libdyld.dylib armv7 <977b0ad6f2f433108b4a0324a57cd2ab> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x348a6000 - 0x348a7000  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x30837000 - 0x3083e000  liblaunch.dylib armv7  /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x32142000 - 0x32146000  libmacho.dylib armv7  /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x36bc6000 - 0x36bcd000  libnotify.dylib armv7 <9406297de3e43742887890662a87ab53> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x31d23000 - 0x31d25000  libremovefile.dylib armv7 <402f8956975d3b6fb86ab9b31a43242c> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x361f9000 - 0x361fb000  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7 <9fdc27af7350323bbc7d98e14e027907> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x3535d000 - 0x353ea000  libsystem_c.dylib armv7 <f859ce1ad1773f0ba98d7c6e135b7697> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x30afe000 - 0x30b04000  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7 <27bb5462450732e380f5a2c170546e93> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x31cda000 - 0x31cf8000  libsystem_info.dylib armv7 <50863bcbf478323e96a8e5b1a83ea6f9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x30734000 - 0x3074b000  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7 <311f379a9fde305d80c1b22b7dd2e52a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x327a8000 - 0x327ac000  libsystem_network.dylib armv7 <356cb66612e836968ef24e6e5c3364cc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x30732000 - 0x30734000  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7 <6a8f2f33c7543808a0f4599101c3b61a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x3441c000 - 0x3441d000  libunwind.dylib armv7  /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x30ac2000 - 0x30ad4000  libxpc.dylib armv7  /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x352d8000 - 0x352df000  MobileIcons armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x354b6000 - 0x354c3000  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x36225000 - 0x36226000  liblangid.dylib armv7 <644ff4bcfbf337b5b5859e3f0fc0a9a8> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x34f65000 - 0x34f75000  GenerationalStorage armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x34a84000 - 0x34c42000  ImageIO armv7 <02e3578171fa3b6a969b244275fd2bab> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x3499a000 - 0x3499f000  IOSurface armv7 <443ac3aab9283da480dd9dcda3c5c88e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x35c54000 - 0x35ca1000  CoreTelephony armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x31cd3000 - 0x31cda000  liblockdown.dylib armv7 <9e45ce468a6f31e5b8263f2c224aa800> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x361a0000 - 0x361f9000  CoreAudio armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x35ca5000 - 0x35cb3000  libbsm.0.dylib armv7 <750a0de73a733019a77144b805d4d2f8> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x36e47000 - 0x36e48000  Accelerate armv7 <55b24cf91a8b3532bde6733c96f14c08> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x36173000 - 0x3617a000  MobileKeyBag armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x348a7000 - 0x34980000  vImage armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x375f9000 - 0x375fa000  vecLib armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x33390000 - 0x333db000  libvDSP.dylib armv7 <441b42aca07b3da39feab25f8349918f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x31e80000 - 0x32142000  libLAPACK.dylib armv7 <0e94e9a7e7a334649afaccae0f1215a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x32fd8000 - 0x33083000  libBLAS.dylib armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x352ac000 - 0x352b7000  libvMisc.dylib armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x36d4e000 - 0x36d72000  Bom armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x32583000 - 0x3258c000  ProtocolBuffer armv7 <0e846afacf823d2b8c029cc3010a8253> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x3338b000 - 0x33390000  AggregateDictionary armv7 <3a3a33f3a05538988c6e2bb363dc46a8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x3256f000 - 0x32581000  DataAccessExpress armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x30bcc000 - 0x30bd0000  NetworkStatistics armv7 <7848d8ebad99367cb4f7f4e3fe88e5d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
0x32f8a000 - 0x32f96000  AccountSettings armv7 <373e59421d983c93931cfbad87b1ae35> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x30c34000 - 0x30c7f000  ManagedConfiguration armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x340a1000 - 0x340b8000  libmis.dylib armv7 <258bc92be5823b239b4412dd42cb4807> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x346d7000 - 0x346ec000  PersistentConnection armv7 <54091a638f8731cd85ccf00fa06972c3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x35cb3000 - 0x35cb5000  DataMigration armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x32533000 - 0x3253c000  MobileWiFi armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x31d25000 - 0x31d29000  CaptiveNetwork armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x37c81000 - 0x37c98000  EAP8021X armv7 <952fcfdec0633aff923768fca1a26fcb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x35f43000 - 0x35fea000  AddressBookUI armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x35fea000 - 0x36041000  GMM armv7 <6b2f7e1aa6be3d69b4c4cf54ed960602> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x36041000 - 0x36046000  FTClientServices armv7 <21de970d7ebb3e7fb502a0a5451b0806> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x3075f000 - 0x30764000  libAccessibility.dylib armv7 <9a17d07b5a3b38cfafdf16f78c99b572> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x36536000 - 0x3665c000  JavaScriptCore armv7 <2ffc6c87b94434288366bd53765ee267> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x36ee2000 - 0x36f40000  StoreServices armv7 <6ce256d3cf433e4aa1af8d696bf1f75d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x324cf000 - 0x32533000  IMCore armv7 <046b6b615a743057b59d4aaba8a91d61> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x34c54000 - 0x34c59000  Marco armv7 <8dea3e558fe534ff868fc92e215ce53b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x36131000 - 0x3616f000  FTServices armv7 <3f23418319a03a589dd5cac7df20e238> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x36cbb000 - 0x36cf8000  IMFoundation armv7 <253125b9103c3d13b66923ac6893c25b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/Frameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x36226000 - 0x36253000  libtidy.A.dylib armv7 <3aacc5b650e037c086a8ff6657d154bf> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x3609c000 - 0x3610d000  CoreImage armv7 <86ac6f5a267637b6b7f8a831dfc7c64b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x350b1000 - 0x350c8000  DictionaryServices armv7 <6ed2e967136f37d4a4b9b318d6c43b83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x37165000 - 0x371b7000  CoreText armv7 <5bfac4ee88d03d5b87a1f105abb7756c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x34c9c000 - 0x34d6d000  WebKit armv7 <3c5dd2ec46fe3e189c25bba78ad88fa1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x30c7f000 - 0x3143f000  WebCore armv7 <2690c38c9c5f3c09975d619dd1dfbed7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x36f4c000 - 0x36fc6000  ProofReader armv7 <6db611d8df6530d480f97a40bc519f70> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x34f2f000 - 0x34f54000  PrintKit armv7 <08509c7bc915358b953de6f5cbef5c56> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x314a0000 - 0x314c6000  OpenCL armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x3042d000 - 0x3043d000  OpenGLES armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x30569000 - 0x305a2000  VideoToolbox armv7 <9f25f38d1cd13a1daff99cfde8884410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x327ee000 - 0x32d33000  FaceCoreLight armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x34352000 - 0x3435f000  CoreVideo armv7 <364fa32d513f3c11b50970120545f1a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x33846000 - 0x3384b000  libGFXShared.dylib armv7 <998fccc16cf735dbb62324202995e193> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x30bb7000 - 0x30bba000  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x373b5000 - 0x373ba000  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7 <42dbc26828e934acabb4f3b0a35d8250> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x372bd000 - 0x372fe000  libGLImage.dylib armv7 <40448706190031f6b0d9636cc11ee81d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x36195000 - 0x36196000  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x318f1000 - 0x318f3000  CoreSurface armv7 <97f871f09f503c98a6371c2b657430d8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x37274000 - 0x372bd000  CoreMedia armv7  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x314c6000 - 0x314ce000  AssetsLibraryServices armv7 <38132ecfd74b325fb1a4142bab663c19> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x31919000 - 0x3193a000  libxslt.1.dylib armv7 <39348471007e39dab80af68b08390456> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x37008000 - 0x37052000  libc++.1.dylib armv7 <5b690e5dd5a43a7fb166ade9fe58a7a4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x31d90000 - 0x31e7f000  libiconv.2.dylib armv7 <2cfefe2ad1d335dd9549562910e7a2e2> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x32ed0000 - 0x32ee6000  libresolv.9.dylib armv7 <66f7557fa4b43979b186e00271839fdb> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x34506000 - 0x34542000  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7 <55941c96cf1f3b048e72a148c4496c16> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x300ff000 - 0x30119000  libRIP.A.dylib armv7 <1828cddc5dd93c61afbefb59587d7f8a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x34a17000 - 0x34a32000  CoreServicesInternal armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesInternal.framework/CoreServicesInternal
0x37052000 - 0x37132000  RawCamera armv7 <293f818ba6533dceae8b900b6ed3c887> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
0x3215f000 - 0x324cf000  TextInput armv7 <8d7f24642c7634cc8e3a6e65f1dcd98e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x341ed000 - 0x3434d000  libmecabra.dylib armv7 <06a0a1ee488030169bdfab11fc8d2c5c> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
0x37b76000 - 0x37c3d000  GLEngine armv7 <6617f2b4ee283469a5595129889ff049> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine
0x35de8000 - 0x35eb8000  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7 <49607ffe4ee9389494285a213e392924> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x3743e000 - 0x37545000  IMGSGX543GLDriver armv7 <7454a840600038949d67edad05097242> /System/Library/Extensions/IMGSGX543GLDriver.bundle/IMGSGX543GLDriver
0x31d04000 - 0x31d0a000  libGPUSupportMercury.dylib armv7 <3c1cc3175c403ace8fcbd3826bd43807> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUSupport.framework/libGPUSupportMercury.dylib
0x309fc000 - 0x309ff000  libCoreFSCache.dylib armv7 <808518e0fbf539af8489f028ca5198c7> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x34a54000 - 0x34a67000  DataDetectorsUI armv7 <50ea319aaeb7307e92719980dd4b2953> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsUI.framework/DataDetectorsUI
0x327da000 - 0x327ee000  DataDetectorsCore armv7 <3f4596cbe1b13fdcb427d87de21df3f6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore
0x364b8000 - 0x364f8000  QuickLook armv7 <802b1092542a3017a0380632502610d4> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x3148a000 - 0x3148e000  libgermantok.dylib armv7 <94278987ba623a35ae545db5636b4370> /usr/lib/libgermantok.dylib
0x3262b000 - 0x3263f000  AssistantServices armv7 <4a0843742f363a8885b8db13b44ae256> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssistantServices.framework/AssistantServices
0x37135000 - 0x3714c000  VoiceServices armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VoiceServices.framework/VoiceServices
0x32ee6000 - 0x32f40000  IMAVCore armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMAVCore.framework/IMAVCore
0x31d1d000 - 0x31d23000  CrashReporterSupport armv7  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x5231000 - 0x5242000  Riven armv7 <46e4d9c7b88d3afca369efb40e3ff4d5> /System/Library/TextInput/Riven.bundle/Riven
```

Comment: I have 4.3.5 (8L1), 5.0.1 (9A405), 5.1.1 (9B206) under my iOS DeviceSupport directory. When you say it is missing the UUID what UUID exactly? Is that one of the spots where `[TODO]` is listed? To be honest I am not exactly sure how to check which version of PLCrashReporter we are using, I don't see any versions listed in the headers, the Info.plist in the Framework directory states 1.0 for the bundle version but I am not sure if that is correct. Based on http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/#Download I would say we are using 1.0 since we implemented it before September 2011.

Comment: No, the `[TODO]` part is just fine. The `Binary Images` section at the bottom has information which file has to accessed to get the symbols for each address. The file name is one part, but to identify if the file is really right, each binary has a `UUID`. Now with most libraries there is a `armv7 <UUID>` part in the string, but for the libraries like `Foundation` the line down there is missing the `<UUID>` part in the string. Hence the exact file could not be identified which is need to translate the addresses into symbols.

Comment: I highly recommend using at least the PLCrashReporter version that is bundled with the QuincyKit SDK I linked above. If not using a service to handle your crash reports. As mentioned, I am one of the developers of the QuincyKit client and also the HockeyApp.net service that you might want to check out.

Comment: Very informative Kerni and thanks for your contribution to QuincyKit, we are using it now for collecting the crash reports from the device, but again it is an older version. I'll get us underway on updating with what is on github and hopefully we'll get some more useful information.